# Bootstrap columns not working in IE11 (Flex)

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4, internet-explorer-11

I have the following markup:

```css
.hero{
  background:lightgrey;
  padding: 50px 0px;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">

<div class="hero">

  <div class="container d-flex align-items-center">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-12">
        <div class="text__wrap d-flex flex-column">
          <h1>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.</h1>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

</div>
```

In Chrome (and most other browsers), the columns render as expected. However, in IE11, the column doesn't span the `.container`.

I've seen several other questions on this and have tried the following:

```
.text__wrap{
  flex-basis: 100%
  /* flex: 1
  width: 100%; */
}
```

... Neither which have worked. Where am I going wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems the issue is related to the d-flex. Try to remove the `d-flex` from the .container div.

Using the following code:

```
<div class="hero">

    <div class="container align-items-center">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-12">
                <div class="text__wrap d-flex flex-column">
                    <h1>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.</h1>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

</div>
```

The result like this:

[image]

Comment: I removed `d-flex` from `.container` and 'text__wrap` and it worked, thanks. Any ideas why this behaviour came about?